# Viewport device-width and width confusion

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

This is driving me crazy. I designed this responsive website and it works perfect on computer, iPad and iPhone. But not on my android phone. It shows the iPad or the desktop version (both of them look similar so I'm not sure which one)

I'm using a seperate css for phones, and Im all confused with `viewport device-width` vs `width` and `max-width` vs `width`. I think I have jammed them up but finding it hard to find a solution. Can you guys please help me out and let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Also, usually a responsive site shrinks when you resize the browser window, but my site doesn't. Am I doing responsive wrong? Please help.

I tried `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` too but no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `meta` into this one, see if it works:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: mate you have a syntax error in there. It should be `max-width: 480px` not `max-device-width: 480px`. And put `width=device-width` in `meta viewport`

Comment: thanks heaps. That fixed it. But the mobile site looks a little bigger than the screen on Android, any thoughts on that?